# RESTful API Calls to Snowboy API with Swift 3

Tags: swift, rest, api, swift3, voice-recognition

I'm a mobile app noobie currently trying to send 3 wav voice samples with Swift3 to the Snowboy API server.
Per their documentation [Link Here](http://docs.kitt.ai/snowboy/#restful-api), the request needs to have the following elements:

- Endpoint: https://snowboy.kitt.ai/api/v1/train/
- Type: POST
- Content-Type: application/json
- Required Parameter - token: Secret user token
- Required Parameter - name: name of the recorded hotword that's mentioned in the voice samples
- Required Parameter - voice_samples: A list of 3 voice samples in .wav format encoded as base64 strings

An example of the json they're expecting would look like this:

```
data = {
    "name": "nameOfSample",
    "language": "en",
    "token": "token",
    "voice_samples": [
        {"wave": voicesample1asBase64String},
        {"wave": voicesample2asBase64String},
        {"wave": voicesample3asBase64String}
    ]
}
```

With the following code, I get a 400 status code. Meaning that it recognized the token parameter and authenticated my request but the latter is somehow malformatted:

```
lazy var session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: self.conf)

let url: URL

init(url: URL){
    self.url = url
}

func sendDataToURL (completion: @escaping JSONDictionaryHandler)
{
    var request = URLRequest(url: self.url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let path1 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "voicesample1", ofType: "wav")!
    let path2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "voicesample2", ofType: "wav")!
    let path3 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "voicesample3", ofType: "wav")!
    let paths = [path1, path2, path3]

    let audioFileStrings = paths.map { (path: String) -> [String:String] in
        let audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let filename = audioURL.lastPathComponent
        if let base64String = try? Data(contentsOf: audioURL).base64EncodedString(){
            //print(base64String)
            return ["wave":base64String]
        }else{return ["":""]}
    }

    let parameters = ["token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      "name": "nameOfSample",
                      "language": "en",
                      "voice_samples": audioFileStrings
        ] as [String : Any]
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {return}
    print("sending\(parameters)")
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let uploadTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                print(httpResponse)
                switch httpResponse.statusCode{
                case 200: //successful
                    if let receiveddata = data{
                    print("YAAAY! DATA! \(receiveddata)")
                        do{
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: receiveddata, options: [])
                            print(json)
                        }
                        catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    print("Bad HTTP response code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                }
            }
            if let receivedData = data{

            }

        }
        else {
            print("Error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }



    }
    uploadTask.resume()

}
```

I think it's the voice_samples list that isn't well inserted in the son. Does anybody know how I can construct the request so the Snowboy server accepts it? Thanks!

Comment: That's a well known error. Did you look for it? First and big step in debugging: Locate where/which line causes the crash. Is it `let path1 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "voicesample1", ofType: "wav")!` (or path2? path3)? If so you don't have these files with these names in your Bundle.

Comment: The `print(base64String)` (commented here) worked every time. I removed the second code, it's really the request construction that needs to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a complete list of parameters. Add these:

- age_group
- gender
- microphone

This these parameters i got 201 error. But i used bad wav files.

```
let parameters = ["token": "XXXXXXXX",
                      "name": "nameOfSample123123123",
                      "language": "en",
                      "voice_samples": audioFileStrings,
                      "age_group": "0_9",
                      "gender": "M",
                      "microphone": "test"
```

Comment: There was nth wrong with the code after all huh. They should've marked all the other parameters as required, and not just the ones I used. Thanks @llkenny!